# How to parse through a json array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, promise

By using  node js I generate the array below(2) , by parsing through multiple json files for a particular value.

My json files contains a list of IDs with their status : isAvailable or undefined.[image]

So In my code i parse through all my json files but looking only for the first ID and get the statuts of Availability in the picture bellow. When it's true t means that the ID is available. As you can see the name of the file, it's the date and the hour the json was produced.

So What I want to achieve is write a function or anything simple, where i go through the array you can see in the picture.
Example:
We can see that the status is available for the first file, I wanna recover first file name with status available

> ("{ fileName: '2017-03-17T11:39:36+01:00', 
>          Status: Available }"

when the status stop being available, in our example that would be here ( { fileName: '2017-04-06T11:19:17+02:00', contents: undefined } ) 
get:

> { fileName: '2017-04-06T11:19:17+02:00', Status: unavailable }

(2)
[image]

So here is part of my code where I generate this array :

```
Promise.mapSeries(filenames, function(fileName) {
      var contents = fs
        .readFileAsync("./availibility/" + fileName, "utf8")
        .catch(function ignore() {});
      return Promise.join(contents, function(contents) {
        return {
          fileName,
          contents
        };
      });
    }).each(function(eachfile) {
      if(eachfile.contents){
        jsonobject = JSON.parse(eachfile.contents);
        if(jsonobject && jsonobject.hasOwnProperty('messages'))         
       // console.log(jsonobject.messages[0].message.results[2]); 
        eachfile.contents = jsonobject.messages[0].message.results[1].isAvailable;
      } 
      eachfile.fileName = eachfile.fileName.substring('revision_'.length,(eachfile.fileName.length-5));
    console.log(eachfile);

    })
```

May someone help me please

Thank you,

Comment: You haven't explained what is going wrong, and what the context of your application is. Try giving us an example of how the process should look like if it worked like you wanted it to.

Comment: OK, I'm gonna try to explain better.
Thank you for your feedback

Comment: Is it better now?

Comment: Yes it is more clear, still unclear what the problem is though, what is going wrong? I can't run the code you provide, so I need to understand specifically what you want help with

Comment: The code I provided works fine, now I wanna work a new part in this code  that will allow me to parse through the second picture in my post. and only get the "file name" and "content" if the status of "content "changes.
Meaning I only want the name of the files where the status changed. I don't want to have all files thats says id is still available or not.
And i don't know how to write that in code.
Thank you, is it a bit clear? ( Sorry I'm french english is a bit hard for me )

Comment: So if I understand correctly you want a piece of code that will run through the array you created, and end up with a result that contains only the records where the 'content' value is different for the first time (every time it changes)?

Comment: Yes yes, thanks god. I'm still trying but I can't achieve it .

Comment: I hope my answer helps  you.

Comment: Yes it's really clear and well explained!
Thank you for taking time to answer and understanding my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have an array:

```
[
   {
      filename : "2017-03-23 00:00:00",
      contents : true
   },
   ...
   {
      filename : "2017-03-23 00:00:00",
      contents : undefined
   },
   {
      filename : "2017-03-23 00:00:00",
      contents : undefined
   },
   {
      filename : "2017-03-23 00:00:00",
      contents : true
   }
]
```

where the ... represents a long stream of objects where the contents value is true.
You want  to end up with a list of objects without consequent objects with the same contents value, meaning the result would look like:

```
[
    {
       filename : "2017-03-23 00:00:00",
       contents : true
    },
    {
       filename : "2017-03-23 00:00:00",
       contents : undefined
    },
    {
       filename : "2017-03-23 00:00:00",
       contents : true
    }
]
```

Im going to use jQuery because this is a javascript framework I am familiar with, but you should be able to translate it with ease to whatever framework you're using.

```
function doit(dataArray) {

    var resultList = [];
    var currentContent = "";
    $.each(dataArray, function(index, value) {
        if(currentContent != value.content) {
            resultList.push(value);
            currentContent = value.content;
        }
    });

    console.log(resultList);
}
```

Note that you need an array with the data that looks like the data in your picture, however, you print every row. You might need to add those rows into a new array, and then pass that array to this function.